# Is the affine Grassmannian manifold a symmetric homogeneous space?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, homogeneous-spaces, symmetric-spaces, affine-grassmannian

I am interested in the manifold of affine subspaces of dimension $k$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, which can be viewed as the homogeneous space
$$ E(n)/(E(k)\times O(n-k)),$$
where $E$ refers to rigid motions and $O$ to orthogonal transformations.
The Grassmannian of vector subspaces $O(n)/(O(k)\times O(n-k))$ is a symmetric space. Is there a chance that the affine Grassmanian also is?